# Adding text for a minimap camera to see

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Battle Royale game using unity. My problem is with Text Mesh Pro (TMP), I heard the you could move it out of the canvas so the player can see floating text. So, I created some text, moved it out of the canvas, and my camera couldn’t see it. Then, I tried to create an empty game object and assigned the TMP component to it, my text wasn’t even visible in the scene view. I tried both Perspective and Orthographic cameras, but none of the show the text. My unity version is 2020.1.11. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your empty object contain a mesh renderer? It seems like mesh renderer is required to show the text.

If you only need to renderer it in canvas, consider using the UI alternative `TextMeshPro Text` instead.

Please follow this guide to deploy TextMesh Pro in your game.

[TextMesh Pro User Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/manual/index.html)